# Setting default template non-type parameter without explicitly specifying rest of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, containers

Firstly, code for reference (don't worry about `<<` overloads, originally everything is in namespace):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

// structures for checking if given variable is container
template <typename Container>
struct is_container : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container<std::vector<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::vector<Ts...>) {return os;}

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container<std::deque<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::deque<Ts...>) {return os;}

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container<std::list<Ts...>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, std::list<Ts...>) {return os;}
//... the rest of containers in like manner, not necessary for this example

//function that prints given container (begin() and end() are required)
//this function is instantiated also for non-printable containers, but then is never called
//that's why I had to overload << operator, so it may instantiate for them
template<template<typename ...>
         class C ,
         typename T>
void print(const C<T>& cont,
           const char& separator = ',',
           const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>& closures = {{'(', ')'}});

//function that prints to console given nested container. Container has to be at least one-level nested
//so it will accept f.e. vector of vectors of ints, but will reject vector of int
template<int Depth,
         template<typename ...>
         class C ,
         typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
void print_nested(const C<T>& cont,
                  const char& separator = ',',
                  const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>& closures = {{'{','}'},{'[',']'},{'(',')'}},
                  unsigned depth = 0 );

//placebo template function to handle calls, where containers aren't nested (kind of fake instantiation)
template<int Depth, typename T>
void print_nested(const T&,
                  const char& ,
                  const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>&,
                  unsigned);

//definition of above
template<int Depth, typename T>
void print_nested(const T&,
                  const char& ,
                  const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>&,
                  unsigned)
{}

//definition of function printing non-nested container
template<template<typename ...> class C , typename T>
void print(const C<T>& cont,
           const char& separator,
           const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>& closures)
{
    std::cout << closures[0].first;
    for(auto it=cont.begin(); it!=cont.end(); )
    {
        std::cout << *it;
        if(++it != cont.end())
            std::cout << separator << " ";
    }
    std::cout << closures[0].second;
}

//definition of main function, which handles printing nested containers
template<int Depth,
         template<typename ...> class C ,
         typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
void print_nested(const C<T>& cont,
                  const char& separator,
                  const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>& closures,
                  unsigned depth)
{
    if(depth < Depth)
        ++depth;
    std::cout << closures[0].first;
    for(auto it=cont.begin(); it!=cont.end(); )
    {
        if(it!=cont.begin())
            std::cout << std::string(depth, ' ');
        if(is_container<typename T::value_type>::value)
            print_nested<Depth>(*it,
                                separator,
                                (closures.size() > 1)?
                                std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>(closures.begin()+1, closures.end()) : closures,
                                depth
                                );
        else
            print(*it,
                  separator,
                  (closures.size() > 1)?
                  std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>(closures.begin()+1, closures.end()) : closures
                  );
        if(++it != cont.end())
            std::cout << separator << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << closures[0].second;
}

void gimme_some_space(std::string anger = "")
{
    std::for_each(anger.begin(), anger.end(), [](char c) {if(c=='!') std::cout << std::endl;});
}

int main()
{
    //cases and calls:
    std::vector<std::deque<std::list<int>>> nested {{{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{7,8,9}},{{9,8,7},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}}};
    std::vector<int> not_nested {1,2,3,4,5};

    print_nested<2>(nested); // target functionality
    gimme_some_space("!!");
    print_nested<0>(nested); // i'd like to omit <0> (set it as default non-type template parameter)
    //print_nested<0>(not_nested); //excluded from overload set, non_nested is not nested
    gimme_some_space("!!!");
    print(not_nested); //call for printing non-nested container
    gimme_some_space("!!!!");
}
```

Does it's job. Here is output:

```
{[(1, 2, 3),
  (3, 4, 5),
  (7, 8, 9)],
 [(9, 8, 7),
  (6, 5, 4),
  (3, 2, 1)]}

{[(1, 2, 3),
(3, 4, 5),
(7, 8, 9)],
[(9, 8, 7),
(6, 5, 4),
(3, 2, 1)]}


(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

My question is: The parameter Depth decides about indents. It always should be equal to level of nesting, for non-nested container it should be 0. But I don't even expect it to somehow retrieve information about how much nested is given container - on the contrary - I'd like to set Depth default value to zero. So in template parameters it should be:

```
int Depth = 0
```

But that complicates the matter. If it has default value, it cannot be placed at the beggining of the parameter list, because Container C, and element of that container T (types of course) aren't default. So let's do that anyway:

```
template<template<typename ...> class C ,
         typename T,
         int Depth = 0,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
```

Almost perfect. Is it?
This now works with Depth set default to 0:

```
print_nested(nested);
```

But what if I now want to specify indents myself. Horror:

```
print_nested<std::vector<std::deque<std::list<int>>>, std::deque<std::list<int>>, 2>(nested);
```

Do you know any mind-blowing method to overcome this?

Comment: Besides the fact that your example is everything but minimal: Why do you want Depth as a template parameter and not as a normal parameter?

Comment: @Anedar Because I would have to place new parameter somewhere in function argument list, and that would break my design in which function parameters decide only what characters are printed, not how they are printed :)

Comment: Template parameters are neccessary if you need different instantiations of a function which need to be seperately compiled - and thats just not the case if the only place you actually use it is in an if-clause. But did you try to move it to the first position and give your other template parameters some random default-value? It should be overwritten anyway if it is deduced from the arguments.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks and no more questions.

Comment: @Anedar you don't even need to "give your other template parameters some random default-value". `template<class=void, class T> void f(T arg);` is perfectly valid by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use extra argument.

How about `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Depth > maxDepth`, so

```
template <std::size_t N> using Depth_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

template<template<typename ...> class C ,
         typename T,
         std::size_t Depth = 0,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
void print_nested(const C<T>& cont,
                  Depth_t<Depth> = {},
                  const char& separator = ',',
                  const std::deque<std::pair<char,char>>& closures = {{'{','}'},{'[',']'},
                  unsigned depth = 0
                  );
```

And call it so

```
print_nested(nested, Depth_t<2>{});
```